# Thread Sudoku program Adjust the number of threads in 27 to 12

Tags: c, multithreading, sudoku

```
int main() {    
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];

    int threadIndex = 0;    
    int i,j;
    // Create 9 threads for 9 3x3 subsections, 9 threads for 9 columns and 9 threads for 9 rows.
    // This will end up with a total of 27 threads.
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {                       
            if (i%3 == 0 && j%3 == 0) {
                parameters *data = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));   
                data->row = i;      
                data->column = j;
                pthread_create(&threads[threadIndex++], NULL, is3x3Valid, data); // 3x3 subsection threads
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                parameters *columnData = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters)); 
                columnData->row = i;        
                columnData->column = j;
                pthread_create(&threads[threadIndex++], NULL, isColumnValid, columnData);   // column threads
            }
            if (j == 0) {
                parameters *rowData = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));    
                rowData->row = i;       
                rowData->column = j;
                pthread_create(&threads[threadIndex++], NULL, isRowValid, rowData); // row threads
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);         // Wait for all threads to finish
    }

    // If any of the entries in the valid array are 0, then the sudoku solution is invalid
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        if (valid[i] == 0) {
            printf("Sudoku solution is invalid!\n");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
    printf("Sudoku solution is valid!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, this program has a total of 27 threads.

First, there are rules when making Sudoku programs.

There are nine 3x3 subsection, using 9x9 grids.

Subsection contains one of the number to 1~9.

Numbers from 1 to 9 are entered horizontally and vertically on the 9x9 grid.

Here, I would like to meet the following conditions

- 9 threads to verify each subsection,
- 1 thread to check the column,
- 1 thread to check the row,
- And the main thread that synthesizes these results = 1

I want to change the total number of threads to 12.

There are already 9 thread 3x3s so there's no problem.

but, there are 9 columns and rows threads.

so, My question is this.

1. If for change the "if(columnData)" and "if(columnData)" in "for Sentence" to 1 threads instead of 9 threads can I take it out of the "for sentence"?
   Or should I change it to + instead of x?
2. If you change it like this i have leave one, but how do you create one main thread that colligation these results? 
   Can you make it data*columnData*rowData?

I am really sorry for beginner coding + poor English skills.

It was too difficult, so I came here and asked for help.

Since the entire source code is 169 lines, only the main function part using the thread is taken.

Finally, thanks in advance to the respondents.
Also, thanks to those who read this post and to "Sarmad Hashmi" who released the source code.

Original source code by [Sarmad Hashmi](https://github.com/sarmadhashmi/multithreaded-sudoku-validator)

Comment: regarding: `parameters *data = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters));`  1) `parameters` is not defined in the posted code, so this will not compile  2) the returned type from `malloc()` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing the cast.  3)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: DO NOT post links to code, rather select/copy/paste the code into your question

Comment: OT: when indenting the code, please make each indent level be 4 spaces, not a `<tab>`

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&threads[threadIndex++], NULL, isColumnValid, columnData);` and similar calls to `pthread_create()`  Always check the returned value. Any value other than 0 indicates an error occurred.  This function does not set `errno` so an error report would look similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "pthread_create() for `columnData` failed\n" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to the question:

Pass the whole 9x9 board to each thread function.  Let the thread function extract the `rows` or `columns` or `sub grids`  Then only three threads are needed.

Each would loop 9 times.

Suggest each thread return (via `pthread_exit()` the final status for that thread, so only 3 returned values need to be checked.

This would allow the elimination of the calls to `malloc()`, the struct `parameters`, etc

Note: the referenced code fails to pass each of the `malloc'd` memory areas to `free()` so the referenced code has 27 memory leaks

Comment: Thank you, sir. I think I can get out of it by returning each thread.
I will try a little more and if there are any problems, I will send message it again.